# Infer generic awaited type from Promise argument

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I have a generic `CacheBuilder` factory witch takes a `GetValue` function in argument and returns an instance of `Cache`

```
type GetValue<T> = (() => T) | (() => Promise<T>)

type CacheBuilder = <T> (getValue: GetValue<T>, options?: BuildCacheOptions<T>) => Cache<T>
```

One thing to note is the `getValue` function can be both sync or async.

I'd like to be able to let Typescript infer T from `getValue`, but to always return the `Awaited` type.

Such as :

```
import { buildCache } from './cache'
// (buildCache is a CacheBuilder)

const getMyVal = () => Promise.resolve('foo')

// Inferred
const cache = buildCache(getMyVal)
```

My trouble is `cache` is inferred as `Cache<Promise<string>>` while I'd like it to be a `Cache<string>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the type `T` in `GetValue<T>`, we can store `GetValue` directly like this, then get the return type of it and "await" it, but with types.

```
type CacheBuilder = <G extends GetValue<any>> (getValue: G, options?: BuildCacheOptions<Awaited<ReturnType<G>>>) => MyCache<Awaited<ReturnType<G>>>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ51vm)

[Awaited type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements)

---

**EDIT after accept:**

Previous concept works perfectly, but here's a cleaner version, with extracted type as generic too (which allows the simple use of `T` inside function implementation)

```
type CacheBuilder = <G extends GetValue<any>, T extends Awaited<ReturnType<G>>> (getValue: G, options?: BuildCacheOptions<T>) => MyCache<T>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDCBDAxgCwgHgCoD4oF4oAlCZAewCcATDAZ2AoEsA7AcwBopcBuAWACgBoSFABCAV0YAbKkjQQA8mGCMyzWtjyEA3lDLLVzAFxduUAL59B-YdADiEYADVEU8ZlwEoACm8BKAjwsAIAfH39AqAAFCjIAW0ZaDxw-ASFwaDl0CWkqCAovDDsoCAAPYAhmKlooB2dXdwxEZhAcTiwS8srqqABBAHdERgqaEmBxCmYsDKKcOZ9WRxc3CBM7Tn0VNVoAfhMcmSzFA23NAPw8OCPNNP485ClECmhydWAoACNJQ5R0EyODnkKFYBAB6UFQACSzAAZvlnlQBK96FBkL8IABGLxfXJHXznPAxeKJCAAOmetDIUgAbhBvAByGFkMj0vypfjI95o%20QAJmx31k6PxkXpHyerKAA)

Comment: Perfect; extends GetValue<any> was the key. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Awaited` on the return type for `Cache`

```
type GetValue<T> = (() => T)
type CacheBuilder = <T> (getValue: GetValue<T>, options?: BuildCacheOptions<T>) => Cache<Awaited<T>>
```

Comment: Partly true because it returns the correct type; but it doesn't fix the auto inference from getValue. See @kelly answer below